# Unique Declaration of VarString inside Replacing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with some replacing code that I use to make Code Editor .

Like a scenario of, when I type a keyword in `RichTextbox` (which served as the code-editor)
sample: i type `"Ac"` in `RichTextbox` (rtb) then supposedly `ComboBox`(declared as lb) will appear.

like a context-hint/intellisense with string inside:

```
public string[] Accep = { "AcceptRejectRule" };
public string[] Acces = { "AccessibleEvents" };
```

then I use a `KeyEvent` args code for If i press Enter after I select in `ComboBox`
the lastword will replace with the word that I type before, like when I type
`"Ac"` all string started with `"Ac"` in `ComboBox` will appear:

--- this is for every word that typed in richtextbox

```
if (token == "letterA" || token.StartsWith("Ac") || token.StartsWith("ac") || token.StartsWith("AC"))
{
    int length = line.Length - (index - start);
    string commentText = rtb.Text.Substring(index, length);
    rtb.SelectionStart = index;
    rtb.SelectionLength = length;
    lb.Visible = true;

    KeyWord keywordsHint = new KeyWord();

    foreach (string str in keywordsHint.ac)
    {
        lb.Items.Add(str);
        lb.SelectedIndex = lb.FindStringExact(str);
    }                   
}
```

--- this is a `KeyEvent` args

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{    
    string Slb = lb.SelectedText.ToString();
    var trimmed = RemoveFromStart(Slb, new String[] { "Ac", "Accep", "Acces" });
    rtb.SelectedText = trimmed;

    lb.Hide();
}
```

Then when I select in `ComboBox` sample I type `"Ac"` for i want to select AccessibleEvent
inside the `ComboBox` ( `"AcceptRejectRule"`, `"AccessibleEvents"` ), when I press Enter
output will be `"AccessibleEvents"` since its been declared that `"Ac`" will remove in
replacing code above and inside this parameter:

```
//Replacing Parameter:
public string RemoveFromStart(string s, IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    foreach (var x in strings.Where(s.StartsWith))
    {
        return s.Remove(0, x.Length);
    }
    return s;
}
```

But when I type `"Acces"` instead then I select `"AccessibleEvents"` output will be:
`"AccescessibleEvents"` instead of "AccessibleEvent" because "Ac" was the shortest
string that I used in the `RemoveFromStart` method .

Now my question was how to make every string inside within code:

```
var trimmed = RemoveFromStart(Slb, new String[] { "Ac", "Accep", "Acces" });
```

Unique for I can have the `"Accep"` also remove even `"Ac`" was declared as the shortest string.

Thanks a lot in advance and hope you could help me :( .really need help so badly .

Answer (score 0):

I think simply ordering descending would work as longest strings would be matched first:

```
 var trimmed = RemoveFromStart(Slb, 
     (new String[] { "Ac", "Accep", "Acces" })
      .OrderByDescending(s=>s));
```

Side note: consider case insensitive comparison in your code.

Comment: Cannot implicity converttype 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Char>'to 'string' pointing to trimmed in rtb.SelectedText = trimmed;

Comment: it worked but the problem is the shortest string now wasnt working though the longest was working alright now .but i need all string to work at the same time :( .

Comment: I guess you need to clearly describe what you want in the question than... It looks like you matching code finds first match and return - so reordering string seemed like a solution... but apparently you need something else which is likely lost in very long text you posted.

Comment: i want all string to work. if i hit the shortest string output will be the same as when i hit the longest1 .pls help :(

Comment: @user2234790, Get rid of most of the code/text from your question and keep `RemoveFromStart` function plus tests that show expected results (i.e. `RemoveFromStart("accc", new String[] { "Ac", "Accep", "Acces" }); // expecting XXXXXX`) for multiple inputs. I have no idea what "all string to work" mean.

Comment: i.e: when i type "Ac", AcceptRejectRule and AccesibleEvents will appear .then when select AcceptRejectRule from combobox output in rtb will be AcceptRejectRule also since "Ac" was included in RemoveFromStart, i wanted the same output when I type "Accep" in rtb, then "AcceptRejectRule" will remain (done since i already made a filter like for string) . means all string in RemoveFromStart should all work :( but i dunno how to make it all unique ...

Comment: @user2234790, I'm sorry I really don't understand what you have problem with and I don't feel trying to sort your code to be testable/do what you want. Please try to organize code in functions that you understand (and can name reasonably) and maybe you'll solve your problem. Separating input from processing values may be good start... Writing unit tests (not verbal descriptions) would help... Good luck.